# VS Code - Jupyter notebook skipping random lines in output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

My Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code are randomly skipping output lines while using the `print()` function along with the `input()` function.

We can see the behaviour in the **very crude** `while` loop below:

```py
i = 0
print('start')
while True:
    i += 1
    print(f'iteration {i-1}')
    if input(f'input {i} - stop? (y)') == 'y':
        break
print('stop')
```

Here's the code running: [gif version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ62L.gif) / [video version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qIcF.jpg) (can't insert the gif here as this is my very first question)

In the case above:

- "iteration 6" was only displayed after input 7
- "iteration 8" was only displayed after input 9 (which triggered the `break`).

Here only one line was skipped in each occurrence but sometimes this happens with 2 or even 3 lines consecutively. It also happens in codes with no loops whatsoever.

It was hypothesized by an user that the behaviour is due to the numbers output by the code not being related to the input, but this is also not the case, as seen in this other code, now using a finite `while` loop:

```py
x = 0
i = 0
print('start')
while i < 9:
    i += 1
    x = input(f'input {i}:')
    print(f'iteration {i} | input {x}')
print('stop')
```

Here's the second code running: [gif version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osNJb.jpg) / [video version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqt8x.jpg)

In the second code:

- "iteration 2" was only displayed after input 3
- "iteration 3" and "iteration 4" were only displayed after input 4

This behaviour is consistent even after clearing VS Code's cache at `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\Code`

I've searched for settings which relate to the outputs in Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code but found nothing that affects this unexpected behaviour. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code as text and not as an image.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me! Since it was in the embedded gif while writing the question I ended up not writing the code in.

Comment: The numbers output in your code are not related to the input. If you modify the code to output the number entered each time, this problem does not occur. Your problem does exist though, so I suggest you file a report on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues).

Comment: @JialeDu Thanks for your hypothesis. Upon further inspection, however, it was observed that the unexpected behaviour persists even when the output contains the input. As you suggested, I'll file a report on GitHub.